# How to specify a preferred column for items in grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to have my `blue` items prefer to be placed on the left side and all my `red` items prefer to be placed the right side. All items should start from the first row and if there are more one type, they should be able to use the other column.

With some help from @Temani Afif, I tried this, but it doesn't work as they are not wrapping into the other column.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .25rem;
}

.foo {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}
.bar {
  background: red;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item foo">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Here the red items start from the first row like the blue items and the blue items can wrap into the second column if there is an uneven amount of items.

Is this possible with css?

Comment: add `grid-auto-flow: dense` to the container

Comment: Nice! But that doesn't seem to help with the wrapping? Without the wrapping I might as well just put them in separate lists right?

Comment: are the number of red elements known or have a max value?

Comment: No, there can be any number of blue and red elements, even 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the position of the red only and use `grid-auto-flow: dense`. Then the trick is to consider `order` as well

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: .25rem;
}

.foo {
  background: blue;
}

.bar {
  background: red;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  order: -1;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item foo">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item bar">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item foo">Item 11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will wok only if the number of blue items is greater than the red ones. But I don't think it can be done better with CSS only, upvoted anyway.